# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, migration, laravel-5.5

I have `users` table where i am storing all **students** and **teachers** details.

**teachers** can create **students**, these reference is stored in `users_references` table.

users table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
{
     $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('uniqueid')->unique();
     $table->integer('contactnumber');
     $table->string('password');
}
```

users_references table

```
    Schema::create('users_references', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('userid');
        $table->integer('teacherid');
        $table->enum('status',['A','I']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('userid')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('teacherid')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

while migrating i am getting an error

Comment: Which error have you?

Comment: thanks for interest. problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding unsigned() in the users_references table for  id. 
Laravel's increments('id') function creates an unsigned integer, so the foreign key column also needs to be unsigned.

Comment: Welcome akhil :)